# Search of names of people and organizations with regular expressions (python)

Tags: python, regex, search

In the book 'Natural Language Processing with Python. there is exercise: to tokenize all names of people and organizations using nltk.regexp_tokenize()

Problem: the function returns the first words in a sentence which can be as desirable word as undesirable one.

Question: how to make this search more specific? In my case I use the following pattern: '[A-Z][a-z]+'

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Your regex matches capitalized words. Regex-es by definition do not care about the meaning of a word, they only match patterns, so I don't think it's possible to do that just by using a pattern (i.e. you can't distinguish whether a word is used as a personal name or a noun if they have have the same spelling).